# Quote for a full week of sprint/workshop - How to price this?

Tags: fixed-price, scope-of-work, startups

I am looking for advice on how to price work on a week-long  intensive workshops.

I have done 2-3 days sessions before but that was usually basically a set of meetings in some corporate 9-5 office, everything was preset and scheduled, the aim was mainly to go through some data with relevant people and get everyone on the same page (distributed teams...).

This is different though, it's in the startup industry and it's going to be a sprint-like week of defining and developing an initial product. I assume I might need to work until late at night and in general the work will be less defined (things like ideation...)

So I don't know how to price this. Previously I would go from my hourly rate as the time spent was quite well defined but that doesn't seem to work well in this case. The workshop will happen in a rented house where everyone will both stay and work for the whole week.

My travels and stay are paid for, I just need to come up with a reasonable way to price my work.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd charge my **day rate** as a base.

**You can figure day rate, based upon desired annual salary *[here](https://www.whatismydayrate.com/)***

If work is expected to go into late hours of the day, and extend well past 8hrs per day, then I'd **double** my day rate.. 16hrs per day. Then multiply by total days of work. So for a7 days... `day rate x 14`

Granted that only leaves 8hr to sleep then start working again. However, given that you would essentially be "locked in" to this one client and this one project for all your time, it is not unreasonable to charge a bit more due to the lack of attention you'll be able to give your business as a whole. So I wouldn't bother factoring time off for meals or due to an hour or two prior/after work.